# ¿Se puede consultar la hora a un servidor NTP desde Ionic/Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic, date, npm

quiero consultar la hora a través de un servidor NTP, para ello he importado la librería @hapi/sntp en mi proyecto y al compilar me sale el Error: "No se encuentra módulo 'dgram' y 'dns'. He estado investigando y para hacer este tipo de consultas se realiza a traves del protocolo UDP y parece ser que no es muy amigo de las aplicaciones Web. ¿Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerse? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me temo que por lo pronto, no es factible utilizar UDP desde el browser. Los navegadores utilizan el protocolo http (o WebSockets) para soporte. Ambos protocolos están sobre TCP.
En este caso, lo que se puede hacer es crear un "proxy" en el backend al que invoques desde  el browser (REST API). Esta API puede a su vez, recuperar la hora con el servidor NTP y una vez obtenida la respuesta, retornarla al browser.
El cómo exactamente hacerlo, dependerá de la plataforma que tengas como Backend.